# How to apply validation in graphQL schema using graphql-constraint-directive

Tags: graphql, gqlquery

```
import { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-express';
const { constraintDirective, constraintDirectiveTypeDefs } = require('graphql-constraint-directive');

schema: mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [
    makeExecutableSchema({
      resolvers: resolver,
      typeDefs: [constraintDirectiveTypeDefs, typeDefs],
      schemaTransforms: [constraintDirective()]
    }),
  ],
})
```

I am referring this pacakge:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-constraint-directive.

I am getting this error in loading types on my console after implementing it:

```
Error: Directive "constraint" may not be used on ARGUMENT_DEFINITION.
```

How to apply validation at schema level?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use makeExecutableSchema from **apollo-server-express**.

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive), makeExecutableSchema from **graphql-tools** should be used.

Solution:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express')
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools')
```